# MySQL REPLACE statement incorrect? "A new statement was found, but no delimiter"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to replace substrings in the fields of a table, but phpMyAdmin says 
*"A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one' (near REPLACE)"*
I've digged through the documentation, but found no hint on what I could do. Also, a web search doesn't yield helpful results...

My statement:

```
update phpbb_users
SET user_avatar = REPLACE(user_avatar, 'http://', '//') WHERE user_avatar LIKE ('http://%');
```

I get a similar error message when trying it with

```
update phpbb_posts
SET post_text = REPLACE(post_text, 'http&#58;//', '//') WHERE post_text LIKE ('http&#58;//');
```

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [appears to have been a bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12020) with that (outdated) phpMyAdmin version; it's fixed at least in the current 4.5.5.1, possibly earlier but I didn't test extensively to find when exactly.