# Update Table with values from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

SQL Question. I put the system_id as the partent_id vs. the appropriate parent_id which is the tables company_id.  So I was trying this, but am getting several errors:

```
update justmarket.companies e, (Select DISTINCT company_id from justmarket.companies where parent_id = system_id) c
set e.parent_id = c.company_id
where e.company_id = c.company_id
```

End the error:

> Error Static analysis:
>
> 6 errors were found during analysis.
>
> An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 31) Unexpected
> token. (near "(" at position 31) A new statement was found, but no
> delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "Select" at position
> 32) Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 112) Unexpected token.
> (near "c" at position 114) A new statement was found, but no delimiter
> between it and the previous one. (near "set" at position 117) SQL
> query: Documentation
>
> update justmarket.companies e, (Select DISTINCT company_id from
> justmarket.companies where parent_id = system_id) c set e.parent_id =
> c.company_id where e.company_id = c.company_id
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Table:
company_id   company_name system_id parent_id
1             Name1         55121      0
2             Name2         52211      55121
3             Name3         55444      55121

What I'm looking to do
company_id   company_name system_id parent_id
1             Name1         55121      0
2             Name2         52211      1
3             Name3         55444      1

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I think the first errors are bugs in PhpMyAdmin, it doesn't understand multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608945/mysql-replace-statement-incorrect-a-new-statement-was-found-but-no-delimiter for another query that gets that error.

Comment: updated with examples and I'm on MySQL 5.6.35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using explicit `JOIN` syntax without using a subquery.

```
UPDATE companies AS e
JOIN companies AS c ON e.company_id = c.company_id
SET e.parent_id = c.company_id
WHERE c.parent_id = c.system_id
```