# Update Value in next Row MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mariadb

What should i query to update the next ROW2 and so on which will be deducted from previous row.

Update tbl SET BAL= ''

Row 1 which has 10 QTY and 5 BAL

on the next Row 2, get the Previous BAL which is 5 then substract  1 QTY in Row 2, then update the Row 2 BAL = 4 and so on.

My Table

| Row | QTY | BAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 |

DESIRED OUTPUT

| Row | QTY | BAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 |

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: 10.1.37 mariadb

Comment: You should really upgrade your MariaDB version, even 10.2 will allow you access to CTEs which will make this much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE MyTable, ( SELECT `Row`, `QTY`,
                         @balance := @balance - QTY AS BAL
                  FROM MyTable
                  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @balance := QTY + BAL
                               FROM MyTable
                               ORDER BY `Row` LIMIT 1 ) as init
                  ORDER BY `Row` ASC) data_for_update
SET MyTable.BAL = data_for_update.BAL
WHERE MyTable.`Row` = data_for_update.`Row`;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2217b7148a13d0aa85a4d2cde69d6795)

---

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
JOIN ( SELECT t1.`Row`, t1.QTY, t3.init_balance - SUM(t2.QTY) BAL
       FROM MyTable t1
       JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.`Row` >= t2.`Row`
       CROSS JOIN ( SELECT QTY + BAL init_balance
                    FROM MyTable
                    ORDER BY `Row` LIMIT 1 ) t3
       GROUP BY t1.`Row`, t1.QTY, t1.BAL, t3.init_balance) data_for_update 
                ON MyTable.`Row` = data_for_update.`Row`
SET MyTable.BAL = data_for_update.BAL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=aa8244a989efbf6dbb79c8693e46a3c7)

Comment: thanks I've already try it but when im trying to add this code  in my query in mysql i got UPDATE MyTable, ( SELECT `Row`, `QTY`,
                         @balance := @balance - QTY AS BAL
                  FROM MyTable
                  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @balance := QTY + BAL
                               FROM MyTable
                               ORDER BY `Row` LIMIT 1 ) as init
                  ORDER BY `Row` ASC) data_for_update
SET MyTable.BAL = data_for_update.BAL
WHERE MyTable.`Row` = data_for_update.`Row`;

SELECT * FROM MyTable;

Comment: An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 16)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 16)
A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "SELECT" at position 18)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 339)
Unexpected token. (near "data_for_update" at position 341)
A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "SET" at position 358)

Comment: @SprakenDude This is NOT MySQL/MariaDB error message. Refer to your programming language user manual.

Comment: @Akina sure it is. For example, here's an almost identical [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555324/update-table-with-values-from-same-table), unfortunately with an answer that wouldn't help here.

Comment: @Nick One more variant, without variables and in JOIN form, added. Test it. PS. I cannot find the fiddle with MariaDB 10.1.

Comment: I used  your first solution. Thanks @Akina already  solved my problem. It's really a big help for my project. thanks a lot.