# Get records from mysql, if we enter without space but we get the records with space

Tags: mysql

This is my table

#### id    name             age

1      david raj                  25
2     Md saleem                30

Send value to where clause without spaces but we want the result with spaces.
this is my query like this.

Select * from table where 'name' = "davidraj"

Get the results like this

id    name    age
1    david raj   25

Comment: hay r u there ?

Comment: i got this error while iam using replace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608945/mysql-replace-statement-incorrect-a-new-statement-was-found-but-no-delimiter

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results with spacing by using like query , check the query below,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'name' LIKE "david%";
```

This will return the name starts with david and you can get the result as your need.

Comment: your query will return the names ending with david. It will not return name starting with david

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE replace(name,' ','')= 'davidraj';
```

note: it won't guarantee the correct results, e.g. if you search for "david" it will return a "d avid" as well as a "david"

Comment: query amended now

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
where 
REPLACE(name,' ','') =  'davidraj'
```

Answer (score 0):

User `LIKE` operator to find desired result.

```
SELECT *  FROM table where REPLACE(name, ' ', '')  LIKE '%davidraj%'
```

For more info please visit.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php

Answer (score 0):

you if want to get result using first part of the name then use like which will match david and after all text so your result will check david_test1,david_raj etc

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'name' LIKE "david%";
```

and if you want to get result using full name then remove space then select cause replace function remove space from david raj and make davidraj so you can get result easily

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE replace(name,' ','') = "davidraj";
```

for more information

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php