# MYSQL error: A new statement was found but no delimiter between it and the previous one

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to update my column with that simple query:

```
 UPDATE products SET desc='1' WHERE  1
```

But i get  this error message : A new statement was found  but no delimiter between it and the previous one. If I change desc column to another column than the query is working properly.

I saw [THERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608945/mysql-replace-statement-incorrect-a-new-statement-was-found-but-no-delimiter) that this is a bug, I updated my phpmyadmin to the latest version 5.1, but I still get this error message, what could be the problem?

Comment: `desc`  is a reserved word, try `"desc"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DESC is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) used in ordering the results of a query.

> Keywords are words that have significance in SQL. Certain keywords,
> such as SELECT, DELETE, or BIGINT, are reserved and require special
> treatment for use as identifiers such as table and column names. This
> may also be true for the names of built-in functions.
>
> Nonreserved keywords are permitted as identifiers without quoting.
> **Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as
> described in Section 9.2, “[Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)”**:

As I have highlighted above, you can quote a reserved word if you want to use it as identifier, using

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (`)

So you just need to change your query a bit adding the backticks.

```
UPDATE products SET `desc`='1' WHERE  1;
```

You can see a little example [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jyQPpUEVDTwXqdyUWM5CTA/1).